# How to hide login script (batch file) while it is running?

Tags: batch-file

I have created login script using batch file. But actually I need this batch runs invisible (but still showing on the task manager).

As far that I can go is that I only able to minimize the batch file using below code:

```
if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized
set minimized=true
start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"
goto :EOF

:minimized

@echo off

echo        *Logon Script*  

rem :Time_Set
rem echo Setting the system time...
rem net time \\EX001LT /set /y
rem echo.
```

I have tried using cmd /c "batchfile" and didn't work.

Comment: What about `start "" /B "%~f0"` to restart the batch file without opening a new console window as explained by help of command __START__ on executing in a command prompt window `start /?`?

Comment: where should I put this command start "" /B "%~f0" is it inside the login script bat or adding new line?

Comment: The __START__ command line posted by me replaces the __START__ command line in your batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbs to hide the batch completely. Add the path to the logon script to `MyScript.Run` line.

**Hidden.vbs**

```
Set MyScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\path to batch\logonscript.cmd", 0, False
```

Then simply call the **Hidden.vbs** file instead of the batch file